# How to sort transitioning bar charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a project where i am trying to use transitions to display data for years 1800-1805

I have created a bar chart and could get the transition, but the problem here is that i am trying to sort the bar chart so that the data will be displayed in descending order.  how ever when i sort the data and do the transition instead of changing the "y" attribute values of rectangles my code is replacing the existing rectangles to the sorted ones for every single transition.

I want my code in such a way that the rectangles should move its position to its new position from current one .

How could i do that.

My data is as below

year 1800

China - 20000
USA    - 80000
France - 15000

year 1801

China - 25000
USA  -90000
France - 35000

now for this data my code is replacing France and china data it is not moving up and down. what should i add in my code to do that?

```
main.js
-------------

/*
*    main.js
*    Mastering Data Visualization with D3.js
*    2.5 - Activity: Adding SVGs to the screen
*/
var margin = { left:80, right:20, top:50, bottom:100 };

var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var g = d3.select("#chart-area")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
var time = 0;
/*var xLabel = g.append("text")
    .attr("y", height + 200)
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("GDP Per Capita ($)");
var yLabel = g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("x", -170)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Life Expectancy (Years)")*/
var timeLabel = g.append("text")
    .attr("y", height +100)
    .attr("x", width + 100)
    .attr("font-size", "40px")
    .attr("opacity", "0.4")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("1800");
  var data =      d3.json("buildings.json").then(function(data){
            // console.log(data);

            // Clean data
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.Year = +d.Year;
                d.Budget=+d.Budget;
            });



const formattedData = data.map(function(year){
    return year["countries"].filter(function(country){
        var dataExists = (country.budget);
        return dataExists
    })
});

// Run the code every 0.1 second
d3.interval(function(){
    // At the end of our data, loop back
    time = (time < 5) ? time+1 : 0
    update(formattedData[time]);
}, 10000);

// First run of the visualization
update(formattedData[0]);

})

function update(data) {
// Standard transition time for the visualization
var t = d3.transition()
    .duration(10000);

// JOIN new data with old elements.
var rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(data, function(d){

    return d;
});

// EXIT old elements not present in new data.
//rects.exit()
    //.attr("class", "exit")
    //.remove();
// ENTER new elements present in new data.

   rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "enter")
    //.attr("fill", function(d) { return continentColor(d.continent); })
  //  .merge(rects)

        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d,i){

          return i*20;
        }).transition(t)
        .attr("width", function(d,i){
          return d.budget/100;
          console.log(d.budget);
        })
        .attr("height", 18)
        .attr("fill",function(d,i){
if(d.country=="Italy")
{
  return "green";
}else if(d.country=="Australia"){
return "blue";

}

        });

// Update the time label
timeLabel.text(+(time + 1800))



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just the key function, which is fundamental for achieving object constancy.

Right now you have this:

```
var rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(data, function(d){
    return d;
});
```

Which returns `d`, that is, the whole datum. Given your data structure, the datum is an **object**.

However, the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data) is clear about the value returned by the key function:

> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in data is assigned to the first selected element, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on. A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing a **string** identifier for each datum and element. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, change the key function to:

```
var rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(data, function(d){
    return d.country;
    //string---^
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i have changed it as required, but  how to sort the bars?

Comment: This is **another** issue. Please keep just one issue per question here at Stack Overflow. If you have another issue, please post it as a new question, with the relevant details.