# Data visualization is working only for first bar in a bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I have been trying to create an animated bar chart. the bar chart should work in such a way that for a period of 5 years the bar graph shows the values for each country.

Based on the increase and decrease of values the bars should resize itself, however, my bar increases its size whenever there is an increase in value but a decrease in value has no effect on my bars.

And also I have been trying to sort the bar chart for every change in a year and whenever the values change the bars should move its position in descending order, which is not happening either. Please help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/9qp8yt7h/1/#&togetherjs=M4S6aP60Q8

I have tried implementing exit(), but exit is wiping out previous data and starting fresh, which is not what I want, I want the bars to update from the previous value.

```
main.js
-------------

/*
*    main.js
*    Mastering Data Visualization with D3.js
*    2.5 - Activity: Adding SVGs to the screen
*/
var margin = { left:80, right:20, top:50, bottom:100 };

var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var g = d3.select("#chart-area")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom+40)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
var time = 0;

var yLabel = g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("x", -170)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Life Expectancy (Years)")
var timeLabel = g.append("text")
    .attr("y", height -50)
    .attr("x", width -500)
    .attr("font-size", "40px")
    .attr("opacity", "0.4")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("1800");

  var data =      d3.json("buildings.json").then(function(data){
            // console.log(data);

            // Clean data
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.Year = +d.Year;
                d.Budget=+d.Budget;
            });



const formattedData = data.map(function(year){
    return year["countries"].filter(function(country){
        var dataExists = (country.budget);
        return dataExists
    })
});

// Run the code every 0.1 second
d3.interval(function(){
    // At the end of our data, loop back
    time = (time < 5) ? time+1 : 0
    update(formattedData[time]);
}, 2000);

// First run of the visualization
update(formattedData[0]);

})

function update(data) {
// Standard transition time for the visualization
var t = d3.transition()
    .duration(2000);


var rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(data, function(d){
console.log(data);
    return d;
});



   rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "enter")

   .merge(rects)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d,i){
          return i*20;
        }).transition(t)
        .attr("width", function(d,i){
          return d.budget/250;

        })
        .attr("height", 18)
        .attr("fill",function(d,i){
  return d.fill;
});


timeLabel.text(+(time + 1800))



}
```

I want my bar chart to update values for every year and display the same on screen while sorting and re-positioning itself

https://jsfiddle.net/9qp8yt7h/1/#&togetherjs=M4S6aP60Q8

Comment: I provided a detailed explanation for one of the problems in your code in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55680928/5768908), and not only you failed to acknowledge the answer but you kept the same error in this new question. If you ignore people trying to help you users will simply give up. Besides that, your fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: I have changed the code as you have mentioned in the previous example, however, after changing the transition stopped working and there are many issues that I am facing which I tried to address in that question itself , but I was asked to open a new discussion for new issues, so here I am trying to find out .

Comment: You should fix one problem at a time, and the key function was clearly one of them. Now your question asks about one specific problem but it has other problems as well (already addressed), making it hard for people trying to help you. Anyway, good luck.